# Insert records in ado.net data model using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to ado.net data model and i need to insert some records from my application to database.

**Code Snippet**

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (SampleEntities db = new SampleEntities())
                {
                    User obj = new User();
                    obj.username = model.UserName;
                    obj.password = model.Password;
                    obj.datecreate = DateTime.Now;
                    db.AddToUser(obj);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

But i am getting error like SampleEntity does not contains definition for  **AddToUser**(are you missing a using directive or an assembly references).

**Updated**

I had try to add object with my entity to insert the records in database getting error.

[image]

Comment: Depending on the EF version you use, it might be : `db.User.Add(obj)`

Comment: it would be db.users.add(obj)

Comment: I had tried this following code too but i cant inside the records..

Comment: just change user obj = new user() to t_user obj=new t_user()

Comment: Its Working fine... Thank you coder1409...:)